# How to know main isolate is exited in background isolate

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm using [workmanager](https://pub.dev/packages/workmanager) package to launch a background task and communicate with main Isolate.

In `main.dart`, my code is like:

```dart
Future main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  // call Workmanager().initialize()
  await BackgroundService().init();
  // init ReceivePort
  var port = ReceivePort();
  if (IsolateNameServer.lookupPortByName('bChannel') != null)
    IsolateNameServer.removePortNameMapping('bChannel');
  IsolateNameServer.registerPortWithName(port.sendPort, 'bChannel');
  port.listen((dynamic data) async {
    print('[Main][bChannel listener] got $data');
    // send http request and update ui
  });
  BackgroundService().registerPeriodicTask();
  print('[Main] init');
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

In `background_service.dart`, my code is like:

```dart
void callbackDispatcher() {
  Workmanager().executeTask((task, inputData) async {
    try {
      switch (task) {
        case 'a':
          print("[Background] Task A triggered.");
          var sendPort = IsolateNameServer.lookupPortByName('bChannel');
          if (sendPort != null) {
            sendPort.send('message from background');
            print("[Background] message sent.");
          } else {
            print("[Background] no send port.");
            // send http request in background and save result to SharedPreferences
            final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
            await prefs.setString('result', 'result_message');
          }
          print("[Background] Task A finished.");
          break;
      }
      return Future.value(true);
    } catch (e) {
      print("[Background] $e");
      return Future.value(false);
    }
  });
}

class BackgroundService {
  // singleton things
  static final BackgroundService _instance = BackgroundService._internal();

  factory BackgroundService() {
    return _instance;
  }

  BackgroundService._internal() ;

  void registerWeatherRefreshPeriodicTask() {
    Workmanager().registerPeriodicTask(
      'TaskA',
      'TaskA',
      initialDelay: Duration(minutes: 1),
      frequency: Duration(minutes: 15),
      constraints: Constraints(
        networkType: NetworkType.connected
      )
    );
  }

  Future init() async {
    Workmanager().initialize(
      callbackDispatcher,
      isInDebugMode: true,
    );
  }

}
```

It works when app running in front and in background. However, if the app exits (tap Back) on Android, I would see logs like

```
I/flutter ( 8342): [Main] init
D/FlutterLocationService( 8342): Unbinding from location service.
D/FlutterLocationService( 8342): Destroying service.
I/flutter ( 8342): [Background] Task A triggered.
I/flutter ( 8342): [Background] no send port.
I/flutter ( 8342): [Background] Task A finished.
```

There is no logs to indicate that main Isolate consumes the message. From [ReceivePort document](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-isolate/ReceivePort-class.html):

> A ReceivePort is a non-broadcast stream. This means that it buffers incoming messages until a listener is registered.

And when I open the app again, it will show `[Main] init` again. So I guess main Isolate has been exited and there is no listener to the port.

What I'd like to do is:

- when app running in front, background task triggers and finally update UI
- when app running in "background" (UI exits but background is actually running), background task triggers and send http requests and save the result. So when app launches again, it can read the result and render UI.

How could I implement this?

Answer (score 0):

I gave up triggering main isolate to render, instead background isolate updates and saves the result, and let main isolate re-render if it's running, otherwise render during the initialization.

In `main.dart`:

```
Future main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  // call Workmanager().initialize()
  await BackgroundService().init();
  // init ReceivePort
  var port = ReceivePort();
  if (IsolateNameServer.lookupPortByName('bChannel') != null)
    IsolateNameServer.removePortNameMapping('bChannel');
  IsolateNameServer.registerPortWithName(port.sendPort, 'bChannel');
  port.listen((dynamic data) async {
    print('[Main][bChannel listener] got $data');
    // refresh shared preferences and trigger render
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    await prefs.reload(); // reload otherwise it will use out-dated data
    // add BLoC event
    bloc.add(refreshEvent());
  });
  BackgroundService().registerPeriodicTask();
  print('[Main] init');
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

In `background_service.dart`:

```
void callbackDispatcher() {
  Workmanager().executeTask((task, inputData) async {
    try {
      // also init and reload shared preferences
      // if main isolate contains other initialization works, it should also put here
      final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      await prefs.reload();
      var httpClient = http.Client();

      switch (task) {
        case 'a':
          print("[Background] Task A triggered.");
          // send http request and save the result
          var response = await httpClient.get(uri);
          await prefs.setString('result', response.body);

          var sendPort = IsolateNameServer.lookupPortByName('bChannel');
          if (sendPort != null) {
            sendPort.send('message from background');
            print("[Background] message sent.");
          }
          print("[Background] Task A finished.");
          break;
      }
      return Future.value(true);
    } catch (e) {
      print("[Background] $e");
      return Future.value(false);
    }
  });
}
```